# jQuery Mobile .listview('refresh') not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, listview, mobile

I'm building a mobile web app with jQuery Mobile and I have a problem. I am using jQuery to parse an XML file and create list items. It builds the list, then apppends that list of `<li>`s to the `<ul>` on the page. I read that in order to get the list to be styled correctly you have to call `.listview('refresh')` after you append the data to refresh the list so that jQuery Mobile can set correct styling to the list.

My problem is that the list never refreshes. It keeps getting styled incorrectly. Am I doing something wrong? Is my code correct? FYI, I have tried all kinds of variations of `.listview()`, `.listview('refresh')`, etc.

CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "podcast.xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      async: false,
      success: parseXml
    });
  });

  function parseXml(xml) {
    var podcastList = "";
    $(xml).find("item").each(function() {
      podcastList += "<li class='ui-li-has-thumb ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-btn-up-c' role='option' data-theme='c'><img src='" + $(this).find("itunes\\:image").attr("href") + "' class='ui-li-thumb'><h3 class='ui-li-heading'><a href='" + $(this).find("enclosure").attr("url") + "' class='ui-link-inherit'>" + $(this).find("title").text() + "</a></h3><p class='ui-li-desc'>" + $(this).find("itunes\\:subtitle").text() + "</p></li>";
    });
    $("#podcastList").append(podcastList);
    $("#podcastList").listview('refresh');
  }
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ran into this problem with code looking similar to yours. My solution was to place the refresh into the $.ajax "complete" option.

```
        complete: function() {
            $('#list-id').listview('refresh');
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#podcastList").trigger("create");
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to use no parameters in the listview method as in

```
<div data-role="page" id="playlist">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>my playlist</h1>
        <a href="index.html" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"></div>
</div>
```

end then..

```
$('#playlist').bind('pageshow', function () {
    doOnCallBack = function(){
        $('#playlist').find('[data-role="listview"]').listview();
    }
    ajaxGet('${genSecureLink(action:'updatePlaylistTemplate',controller:'ajaxActionsPd',absolute:'true')}',$('#playlist').find('[data-role="content"]'),doOnCallBack);
});
```

here is my function ajaxGet:

```
function ajaxGet(url,target,doOnCallBack){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        error:function(x,e){handleAjaxError(x,e);},
        beforeSend:function(){$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();},
        complete:function(){$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();doOnCallBack();},
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){target.html(data);}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spike's answer worked for me -- I was targeting the ul's parent div.  I also needed to bind the ajax function to pagecreate -- that is:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="my-page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Podcast List</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="podcastList" data-role="listview">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$('#mypage').bind('pagecreate',function(){
  // instead of $(window).load(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "podcast.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            async: false,
            success: parseXml
            complete: function() {
               $('#podcastList').listview('refresh');
            } 
        });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good to me... Looks almost exactly like what I have in my app.

Maybe the problem lies in your HTML? It should look something like:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="my-page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Podcast List</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="podcastList" data-role="listview">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```