# jQuery mobile - data loaded form json file to listview breaks after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to improve my **JQueryMobile** \ **JavaScript** skills by building a simple web app that gets a `json` file and loads the data from it into a clickable `listview`.

The goal is to select one of the `li` elements by clicking it using `data-role="button"`, and a new page should be open in a form of a dialog page, by using the `data-rel="dialog"` attribute + attaching the `id` of the new page that should be opened by using `<a href="#newPage" data-rel="dialog"></a>`.
I'm facing two problems:

1. For some odd reason, only the first `li` cell is clickable, while it remains un-populated, as the other `li` cells are populated but not clickable.
2. After I refresh the page, the `ul` breaks and shows all names from the `json` in **one** `li` element. [image]

update - thanks to Jithin Lukose i was able to deal with this issue using the following function:

```
complete: function() {
        $('#namesListView').listview('refresh');
    }
```

jQuery mobile code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="scientists">
    <div data-role="header"><h3>great scientists</h3></div>

    <div data-role="content">
            <div>
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" id="namesListView">
                    <li data-role="button"><a href="#newPage" data-rel="dialog"></a></li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"scientists.json",
    dataType:"json",
    type:"get",
    cache:"false",
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $(data.abc).each(function(index,value){
            console.log(value.name);
            $("#namesListView").append("<li>"+value.name+"</li>");
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4998892/1640577

```
  complete: function() {
            $('#namesListView').listview('refresh');
        }
```

Comment: thanks, it worked, now the list doesnt break. still cant make rest of the list elements clickable.

Comment: $("#namesListView li").live('click',function(){  });

Comment: If you are using jQuery 1.9 + user $(document).on('click','#namesListView li',function(){ })

Comment: it actually detects the clicks, but why cant i use the "data-role="button" attribute to make all the "li" automatically clickable + automatic redirection to the next page via the "<a href="#newPage.." attribute?

Comment: Yes, You can use $("#namesListView").append('<li><a href="'+value.url+'">'+value.name+'</a></li>');

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it works, but its a workaround. How do i apply the "data-role="button" attribute on the li elements without the use of sheer javascript, but rather using the functionality of jQueryMobile?